# Why am I getting "Mean of empty slice" warnings without NaNs?

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a dataframe `keptdata`. I have a for loop to search through the rows of `keptdata`, and at one point need to average the previous values.

This is the relevant line in my code, that produces the warning:

```
avg = np.average(keptdata.iloc[i-500:i].price[keptdata.price != 0])
```

Here `i` is the variable that's being looped over in the for loop, `price` is a column in the dataframe, and I'm including the row in the average only if `price` is not zero.

Why am I getting a warning? Googling for the warning it seems to happen if there are `NaNs` in the dataframe, but I checked for that using `keptdata.isnull.any().any()` which returns `false`.

Another possibility is that if `i-500` is negative, that might be causing problems, but I rewrote the for loop to start with `i = 700` and I still get the warning.
Removing `keptdata.price != 0` seems to resolve the issue, but that changes the line fundamentally.

Can the cause of the warning be fixed? Do I have any options other than suppressing the warning?

Comment: For `i = 0`, `.iloc[i-500:i]` returns an empty slice, how to fix this depends on what you're doing exactly. Simple and lazy, avoid start iterating from `1`, probably better: don't iterate over rows and try to vectorize your code. A [mre] is needed.

Comment: @mozway that should have been avoided when I started with ````i = 700````, right?

Comment: Maybe, but `.price[keptdata.price != 0]` can also produce an empty slice if no values match the criteria. As said above a [mre] would be needed to fully address your question.

Comment: @mozway in an effort to produce a MWE, I think you identified the issue. I had a series of 0's in the price, such that after imposing the condition, there's no slice left. I'll write that as an answer.

Comment: Glad you found out the issue, now if you want some advice try to get rid of the loop, there might be a much more efficient approach than iterating over your rows.

Answer (score 2):

I figured this one out. The problem was the `keptdata` dataframe had a series of at least five hundred 0's for `price`. This means that after inserting the condition `keptdata.price != 0`, there was no longer anything to take an average over, and numpy sensibly returns a "Mean of empty slice" warning.

Answer (score 1):

This happens from the condition you added, maybe you can just make it an if condition as follows:

```
if keptdata.iloc[i].price!=0:
     avg = np.average(keptdata.iloc[i-500:i].price
```